# Am I using "consistent" and "tendency" correctly?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-choice

I have the following sentence:

> We do not need to worry the temperature part since whatever
>   temperature is, the red object is just an `consistent` transformation
>   between blue object and yellow object and will not affect the `tendency` of energy changing.

Here I want to say the transformation will be independent of temperature. I wish to use `consistent` to show this, but I am not sure about it.

For `tendency` part, I wish to use it to mean how the energy will change. For example, if the energy is dropping, in my understanding, the `tendency` of energy changing means the energy dropping.

Also, if you have any suggestions about the formation of this sentence, I am really glad to hear.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*Consistent* seems out of place.

I'd probably rewrite it as

> We do not need to worry *about* the temperature *because* the red object ...

As to how to connect the blue, the yellow and the red objects with respect to energy *trends* (*tendency* relates to *intent*, rather), more context is needed.  Perhaps you could ask another question about the tendency (and energy).